# Django ajax form, choicefields dependancy

Tags: django, forms, jquery, django-forms

## models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()

class ReadBook(models.Model):
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

Also I have one ModelForm:

```
class ReadBookForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReadBook
```

## template.html

```
<form action="/add_report/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**The purpose:**
By default to show a visitor only one field - genre. When he is with done this choice - show other fields from books model, related to selected genre.

Answer (score 2):

inside form tag:

```
{{ form.genre }}
<div id="books"></div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="yes" />
```

then in javascript (jQuery is great for this stuff):

```
$('#{{ form.genre.id }}').change(function(){
    $('#books').load('{% url get_genre_books %}', {genre: $(this).value()})
});
```

you must create a view that will return a html that should be placed in this div:

```
def get_genre_books(request):
    genre = get_object_or_404(pk=request.GET.get('genre', None))
    # here render a template or something that shouls be multiple selector of the books)
    resp = ", ".join(genre.book_set.values_list('title', flat=True))
    return HttpResponse(resp)
```

and of course add this view to the urls.py.

One of many solutions :) didnt' test it (written only here, so maybe small bugs somewhere) :)

Comment: Thanks Jerzyk! I have a similar issue and this is quite helpful :) I am a little confused on where 'book_set' and 'values_list' come from though. Would you mind explaining a tad more?

Comment: `book_set` looks for related Book objects (see [Related objects reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference))

Comment: And `values_list` is a QuerySet that returns tuples instead of objects ([see the entry on values_list in the QuerySet API docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list))